# Redshift - Extracting data based on pattern

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract a sub-string from the below text using a specific pattern in Redshift.

```
value
proda_cat1_subcat_a_jan2020
cat2_subcat_b_prodb_jan2020
```

I am trying to extract the string `cat1_subcat_a` and `cat2_subcat_b` from the above strings.

I tried doing `regexp_substr(value,'cat[^_]')` but this only pulls the string till the first underscore

Expected output:

```
value, output
proda_cat1_subcat_a_jan2020, cat1_subcat_a
cat2_subcat_b_prodb_jan2020, cat2_subcat_b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
cat[0-9]+_[^_]+_[^_]+
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    value,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, 'cat[0-9]+_[^_]+_[^_]+') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The demo is in Oracle, but the syntax should also work on Redshift.

Comment: I am waiting for it to let me accept the answer. Will definitely do it in the next 10 minutes..